# Mobile to Desktop redirection condition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

I couldn't find anywhere PHP version of redirection depending on screen size so I needed to use combined method echo-ing JS script from PHP but the code I found in one of the answers here doesn't work for some reason. All looks fine but the link keeps going back to mobile version regardless. My desktop version link is (sorry can't display  tags here):

```
href="http://www.webaddress.co.uk/?v=desktop" data-ajax="false" rel="external"
```

And at the top of my index.php desktop version I have:

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_GET['v']) && $_GET['v'] == 'desktop') {
$_SESSION['v'] == 'desktop';
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['v']) || (isset($_SESSION['v']) && $_SESSION['v'] != 'desktop')) {
   echo "<script> if (window.screen.width < 1000) {window.location = '/mobile'; }</script>";
}
?>
```

For some reason the redirection finds the second condition always valid.

Comment: I think your parenthesis are off. You're closing your if statement too early.

Comment: If you want to test device size the best approach is a "javascript only" method. Maybe adding this snippet inside the head tag, before loading all your additional scripts/css/fonts/etc..

Comment: In your first `if` statement I'm pretty sure you want to set `$_SESSION['v']` and not compare it against 'desktop'.

Comment: Thank you user555. It obviously works after changing comparison == to =.

Answer (score 0):

In your first if statement I'm pretty sure you want to set `$_SESSION['v']` and not compare it against `'desktop'`.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_GET['v']){
  if ($_GET['v'] == 'desktop') {
     $_SESSION['v'] = 'desktop';
  }
  if ($_GET['v'] == 'mobile') {
     $_SESSION['v'] = 'mobile';
  }

}

if (!isset($_SESSION['v'])) {
   echo "<script> if (window.screen.width < 1000) {window.location = '/?v=mobile'; } else {window.location = '/?v=desktop' }</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Session variables are set using the `=` operator. There is no point in comparing them outside control statements. Also if `$_SESSION['v'] = 'mobile';` we will never get to the mobile site since your `if` statement only works if `$_SESSION['v']` isn't set.

Comment: the idea is the script only needs to detect the screen size and redirect once. once the redirection is done, the $_SESSION['v'] is set accordingly. Once the $_SESSION['v'] is set it doesn't need to check anymore.